# Digimon-like show with a scene where a kid fought bees in the belly of a sea monster

Tags: story-identification, anime

Years ago, I watched a *Digimon*-like show. I have hunted for it, but I don't think it's *Digimon*. Country is America. I saw the show somewhere around 5 or 6 years ago. It was very much an anime. I'm pretty sure it wasn't on live TV, I almost never watched that at the time. Made for kids definitely like *Digimon*age range .

This one kid (white kid, and in the 2010s) was going around and collecting these little chips (like [Appmon Chips](https://wikimon.net/Appmon_Chip)). He could use them to summon cool monsters. There was one time where they fought "bees" in the belly of a sea monster. The kid later summoned the sea monster with a chip.

Some of the bee creatures kinda look like [Combees](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Combee_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) but either they could explode or they were delicious to the sea snake guy.

The sea snake thing looks kinda like a [Seadramon](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Seadramon).

The kid had to collect something near there (or in) I think, so it tried feeding said bee things.

They weren't bees, but they were yellow. They were like pods of a sort that are explosive. He had to defeat the beast with that and grab the chip to get out.

I don't think he was on a boat. I think he rode a turtle of a sort? That, or a bridge of monsters I honestly don't remember which.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Do you recall which channel you saw it on? And can you describe the appearance of the kid or any other characters?

Comment: Hi and welcome. [Here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) is some advice on writing a good identification question. To start with, can you say when "years ago" might have been, and where you would have seen the show (e.g. commercial TV in <country>, on Netflix, etc.)? Was it definitely anime or could it have been a different style?

Comment: How did the kid get into the belly of a sea monster? Was he on a ship out at sea?

Comment: Your last edit didn't clarify whether the kid was on a ship out at sea or not. I'm trying to form a clearer picture of the sort of location/scenery that would've been visible in this episode. Right now, I have no idea where he encountered this sea monster, based on your description.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the question - remove some of the fluff and group the info. Sorry if I've removed something important